# Dynamic dependent dropdown php how to compare two strings?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, dynamic, dropdown

I am trying to compare two strings using ajax and php. I am based on this code https://github.com/webhostguru/dynamic-drop-down. I change the code on the ajaxdata.php file and it looks like this

```
<?php 
include_once 'config.php';

if (isset($_POST['country_id'])) {
    $query = "SELECT * FROM state where state_name=".$_POST['country_name'];
    $result = $db->query($query);
    if ($result->num_rows > 0 ) {
            echo '<option value="">Select State</option>';
         while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo '<option value='.$row['id'].'>'.$row['state_name'].'</option>';
         }
    }else{

        echo '<option>No State Found!</option>';
    }
```

The rest of the code is the same. I change also some of sql tables and i have a state named India to compare the strings with country (India also) but it doesn't work. Any ideas?

Thank you in advance!!!

Comment: Your code is wide open to SQL injection because of the use of user supplied data directly in the sql - use a [Prepared Statement](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)  to mitigate this threat

Comment: In the above sql your POST variable is a `string` yet within the SQL it is **not** within quotes. Again, using a `prepared statement` would have solved this issue completely

Comment: Do some debugging, and see what this `$_POST['country_name'];` gives.

Answer (score 1):

To use a `prepared statement` you can try like this:

```
<?php

    if( isset( 
        $_POST['country_id'],
        $_POST['country_name']
    )) {

        $output='<option selected hidden disabled>Please Select State';

        require 'config.php';

        $query = 'select `id`, `state_name` from `state` where `state_name`=?';
        $stmt=$db->prepare( $query );
        $stmt->bind_param('s', $_POST['country_name'] );
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->store_result();
        $rows=$stmt->num_rows;
        $stmt->bind_result( $id, $name );
        if( $rows > 0 ){
            while( $stmt->fetch() ) $output .= sprintf('<option value="%s">%s',$id,$name);
        }else{
            $output='<option selected hidden disabled>No state found';
        }
        exit( $output );
        
    }
?>
```

---

Based upon the database cited but modified slightly for table names:

```
mysql> select * from tbl_country;
+----+--------------+---------------------+
| id | country_name | time_stamp          |
+----+--------------+---------------------+
|  1 | India        | 2019-12-05 16:29:16 |
|  2 | USA          | 2019-12-05 16:29:16 |
|  3 | Australia    | 2019-12-05 16:29:44 |
|  4 | England      | 2019-12-05 16:29:44 |
+----+--------------+---------------------+

mysql> select * from tbl_state;
+----+-----------------+------+---------------------+
| id | state_name      | c_id | time_stamp          |
+----+-----------------+------+---------------------+
|  1 | Delhi           |    1 | 2019-12-05 16:30:15 |
|  2 | Maharashtra     |    1 | 2019-12-05 16:30:15 |
|  5 | South Australia |    3 | 2019-12-05 17:02:22 |
|  6 | West Australia  |    3 | 2019-12-05 17:02:22 |
+----+-----------------+------+---------------------+

mysql> select * from tbl_city;
+----+------------+------+---------------------+
| id | city_name  | s_id | time_stamp          |
+----+------------+------+---------------------+
|  1 | East Delhi |    1 | 2019-12-05 16:31:42 |
|  2 | West Delhi |    1 | 2019-12-05 16:31:42 |
|  3 | Mumbai     |    2 | 2019-12-05 16:32:49 |
|  4 | Pune       |    2 | 2019-12-05 16:32:49 |
|  5 | Adelaide   |    5 | 2019-12-05 17:03:01 |
+----+------------+------+---------------------+
```

And a marginally different piece of PHP

```
<?php

    #hardcode POST values for testing...
    $_POST['country_id']=1;
    $_POST['country_name']='India';

    if( isset( 
        $_POST['country_id'],
        $_POST['country_name']
    )) {

        $output='<option selected hidden disabled>Please Select State';

        #require 'config.php';
        
        # pertinent to my system
        require '../../dbo/db-conn-details.php';
        require '../../dbo/mysqli-conn.php';
        
        # joining all tables
        $query='select distinct ct.`id`,s.`state_name` from `tbl_country` ct
                    join `tbl_state` s on s.`c_id`=ct.`id`
                    join `tbl_city` c on c.`s_id`=s.`id`
                where ct.`country_name`=?';
        
        
        $stmt=$db->prepare( $query );
        $stmt->bind_param('s', $_POST['country_name'] );
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->store_result();
        $rows=$stmt->num_rows;
        $stmt->bind_result( $id, $name );
        
        if( $rows > 0 ){
            while( $stmt->fetch() ) $output .= sprintf('<option value="%s">%s',$id,$name);
        }else{
            $output='<option selected hidden disabled>No state found';
        }
        exit( sprintf('<select>%s</select>',$output ) );
        
    }
?>
```

Results in generated HTML like this:

```
<select>
    <option selected="" hidden="" disabled="">Please Select State</option>
    <option value="1">Delhi</option>
    <option value="1">Maharashtra</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Are you sure that this code is working, because it's not working for me.

Comment: I did not test it for I have no database with that data. If there are errors please state what they are & I'll look further

Comment: I have use the same database from the github link but i have change a state name to India for this example to see if it is working. When i use this part of your code and i selected a country, the state dropdown displays nothing.

Comment: I just tested a modified query that is relevant to my db and this worked OK

Comment: That db does not have a `state_name` equal to *India*

Comment: Yea i know i already modified it, but it is not showing neither the else output "No state found". It's just a blank dropdown

Comment: If you can uploaded into github all the source code that will helps me a lot! Thank you in advance!

Comment: No can I'm afraid. What else is there anyway? The code above is a near facsimile of your code apart from the database connection scripts which are pertinent to my system only. You might wish to accept the answer if it helped so far though perhaps?